How does a battery reset affect the charging system?
Quite a few weeks ago I was exploring a scan tool on my 2020 Buick Envision. I inadvertently reset the battery. At or around this time, my auto start/stop feature stopped working. And lately I've noticed that my alternator is supplying 14 to 15 volts all the time the engine is running. Normal operation was usually 12.8 to 14 volts changing regularly. Although the battery is 5 years old it tests in great. I'm reasonably sure the reset caused this change. I'm really not concerned about this, but am more curious about why resetting the battery would result in the change. I'm not a fan of the auto/start function so I don't miss that part also.
My question is: Am I right by not being concerned by this, and is there any way to reverse this reset (assuming that's the cause)?

5 years is usually considered a "good" longevity for a battery. I doubt the reset had anything to do with it. I wouldn't know for sure, though. If it is the battery, it would most likely be a coincidence.

I’m pretty sure I’ve found the answer to my question. I’ve searched the internet again and still could not find any registration procedure for this vehicle. I also went to the owners manual. It suggest that this system uses real time readings of the battery’s current condition to help regulate the charging system and does not utilize an intelligent battery sensor. So the option to reregister on my scanner was moog. So I am going to assume that the battery management system is causing these symptoms due to it’s interpretation of the present condition of the battery. I guess I’ll just retest the battery and let my concerns go until I feel it’s time to replace the battery. Thanks for the input.
